# Replace \ with white space

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have `.sh` file in which one of the variable is `admFilter=${10}`, i am receiving value for this variable from `.bat` file call, that's good it's working fine. When i do `echo "$admFilter"` i see my **output**-: `[Name]="Account\List\View"` (It's complete one value)

What i actually want is to remove `"\"` this and replace with **white** space, so final output will be  `[Name]="Account List View"'`  ,  and then store result in another variable, i am not getting how can i use `SED` command on this(Never used it before), i also tried the `tr` command but that combines the string giving `[Name]="AccountListView"'`. Can anyone help me how can i get desired output, and explain little on `sed` if possible? Thanks

**OS VERSION** -: `SunOS 5.10 Generic_150400-52 sun4v sparc SUNW,T5240`

Comment: You might put the following line in your code : `admFilter=${admFilter//\\/ }`. This substitutes the `\\ ` which needs to be escaped with an extra `\\ `. The double `//` states to substitute all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to `bash` ["search and replace"](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace) parameter expansion (explained in the other answer), you can also use **`tr`**:

```
echo '[Name]="Account\List\View"' | tr '\\' ' '
[Name]="Account List View"
```

or **`sed`** (with the [`s` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)):

```
echo '[Name]="Account\List\View"' | sed 's/\\/ /g'
[Name]="Account List View"
```

In both cases, just be sure to escape the backslash (with backslash): `\\`.

Additionally, to store it in another variable, `y`, starting with value in `x`:

```
x='[Name]="Account\List\View"'
y=$(tr '\\' ' ' <<<"$x")
```

Comment: if i try to understand sed , s/ means source after that \\ means replace all , and then / (one we are replacing) with a space, and /g for global? The sed use seems simple and good , i didn't get how tr is working?

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope it's clearer now -- `s` command in `sed` has the format: `s/pattern/replacement/`. To search-and-replace all occurrences of `pattern`, append `g` at the end. The backspace has to be escaped because it's a special character -- used for escaping (for example `\/` in pattern, or `\&` in replacement part), or for referencing capture groups in replacement part, e.g. `\1`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

assuming str contains `[Name]="Account\List\View"`, following variable expansion replaces all `\`  with spaces:

```
str='[Name]="Account\List\View"'
echo "${str//\\/ }"
```

from [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

> ${parameter/pattern/string}
>
> The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string. *If pattern begins with ‘/’, all matches of pattern are replaced with string*. Normally only the first match is replaced. If pattern begins with ‘#’, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of parameter. If pattern begins with ‘%’, it must match at the end of the expanded value of parameter. If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the / following pattern may be omitted. If the nocasematch shell option (see the description of shopt in The Shopt Builtin) is enabled, the match is performed without regard to the case of alphabetic characters. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the substitution operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the substitution operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: ok i will test that, but can you explain use behind //\\/, how is it working?

Comment: the `//` is to replace all matches, a single `/` will replace only first, the \\ is because of escaping meaning of snigle \, the space after the next / is the replacement string